# t-sql 2012 update foreign key value in primary table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

In a special request run, I need  to update `Locker` and `Lock` tables in a sql server 2012 database, I have the following 2 table definitiions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Locker](
[lockerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[schoolID] [int] NOT NULL,
[number] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,    
[lockID] [int] NULL 
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Locker] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
[lockerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = 
 OFF,      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 97)
 ON    [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Lock](
[lockID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[schoolID] [int] NOT NULL,
[comboSeq] [tinyint] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Lock] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
[lockID] ASC
)
```

The `Locker` table is the main table and the `Lock` table is the secondary table. I need to add 500 new `Locker` numbers that the user has given to me to place in the `Locker` table and is uniquely defined by `LockerID`. I also need to add 500 new rows to the correspsonding `Lock` table that is uniquely defined in the `Lock` table and identified by the `lockid`.

Since `lockid` is a key value in the `lock` table and is uniquely defined in the `locker` table, I would like to know how to update the `lock` table with the 500 new rows.  I would then like to take  value of `lockid` (from `lock` table for the 500 new rows that were created) and uniquely place those 500 `lockids` uniquely into the 500 rows that were created for the `lock` table.

I have sql that looks like the following so far:

```
 declare @SchoolID int = 999

 insert into test.dbo.Locker ( [schoolID], [number]) 
    select distinct LKR.schoolID, A.lockerNumber 
    FROM [InputTable] A
    JOIN test.dbo.School SCH 
      ON A.schoolnumber = SCH.type 
     and A.schoolnumber =     @SchoolNumber
    JOIN test.dbo.Locker LKR 
      ON SCH.schoolID = LKR.schoolID 
     AND A.lockerNumber not in (select number 
                                from dbo.Locker 
                                where schoolID = @SchoolID)
    order by LKR.schoolID,  A.lockerNumber
```

I am not certain how to complete the rest of the task of placing `lockerid` uniquely into `lock` and `locker` tables? Thus can you either modify the sql that I just listed above and/or
come up with some new sql that will show me how to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do here but I am pretty sure you want to look at the OUTPUT clause. In short, you would insert into LOCK and use OUTPUT to generate the LOCKER rows. I would also ask why you have SchooID in both tables? Seems to me it doesn't belong in LOCKS. A locker belongs to a school and a lock belongs to a locker.

Comment: Looks like when you create a Locker you need a Lock? You should create an insert trigger on Locker and handle that logic inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `OUTPUT` statement. First you should add rows to the lock table then gram lockid and prepare insert to locker table. This shoul meet your expectations:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (lockid INT)

INSERT dbo.Lock
        ( schoolID, comboSeq )
    OUTPUT Inserted.lockID INTO @tmp ( lockid )
(SELECT
    999,
    1
FROM    master..spt_values sv WHERE sv.type = 'P' AND sv.number <= 500);

INSERT INTO dbo.Locker( schoolID, number, lockID )

SELECT x.schoolID, x.lockerNumber, y.lockid
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT DISCTINCT LKR.schoolID, A.lockerNumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.LockerNumber) rn
    FROM [InputTable] A
    JOIN test.dbo.School SCH ON A.schoolnumber = SCH.type 
    and A.schoolnumber = @SchoolNumber
    JOIN test.dbo.Locker LKR ON SCH.schoolID = LKR.schoolID 
    AND A.lockerNumber not in (select number from dbo.Locker 
    WHERE   schoolID = @SchoolID)
    ORDER by LKR.schoolID,  A.lockerNumber ) x
    JOIN (SELECT t.lockid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.lockid) AS rn FROM @tmp t
) y 
    ON x.rn = y.rn
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you tell me what the following sql is actually doing: 1. (SELECT  999,    1  FROM    master..spt_values sv WHERE sv.type = 'P' AND sv.number <= 500); Would you explain what this means in some detail? 2. ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.LockerNumber) rn, and (SELECT t.lockid, ROW_NUMBER() AS rn OVER (ORDER BY t.lockid) FROM @tmp t how these statements work together?

Comment: First part: `(SELECT 999, 1 FROM master..spt_values sv WHERE sv.type = 'P' AND sv.number <= 500);` it's  query to add 500 rows into lock table. Query use system table `master..spt_values` witch contains numbers. I used it to simple generate 500 rows. Second part: When i instert these 500 rows i get id's but assuming there are other rows in table `Lock` i can't join it with your select because i don't have any field to do it. So i added to both sets new field with somekind of Id to join them together without cartesian product. I used 'ROW_NUMBER' to add sequence of numbers. Thats all.

Comment: 'ROW_NUMBER'  was the only field that could be used or are there other values that could be used? If so, what other fields could have been used? Why did you pick row_number? With your answers here, it will answer my questions.

Comment: There no other to use gor this join. I pick ROW_NUMBER to get sequence numbers from 1 to 500 to make join without cartesian product.

Comment: That answers my questions! Thanks for the help! I am trying to vote that you helped me but it does  work. Would you tell me how to make it so that I can vote on your answer?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
•You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time. You can also use triangle to vote up the answer.

Comment: On your statements how would you change them: 1. JOIN (SELECT t.lockid, ROW_NUMBER() AS rn OVER (ORDER BY t.lockid) FROM @tmp t, the sql has problem with ROW_NUMBER() AS rn  - sql wants ROW_NUMBER() OVER right next to each other, 2. ORDER by LKR.schoolID,  A.lockerNumber ) x sql does not allow order by on derived table. How would you change the sql?

Comment: 1. I corrected query there was mistake with rn field. There was `ROW_NUMBER() AS rn OVER (ORDER BY t.lockid)` enstead `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.lockid) AS rn`  2. You cn remove it from query. It's not necessary to have this statement to run this query.

Comment: How about not being able to use order by?

Comment: I changed query to USE ORDER BY statement.